# Debian Wheezy LXDE: Desktop icons are disappearing, how to restore them?

Tags: debian, lxde

This happens from time to time - I will minimize a window to find out that the Desktop icons have disappeared, and when right-clicking on the Desktop, the Openbox menu is shown. I suspect this is because PCManFM (which manages the Desktop) has crashed.

When this happens, is there a way to restore the Desktop icons, short of logging out and logging back in?

Comment: Yours may be a corner use case. I don't think the average Debian Wheezy LXDE user gives a #$%& about Desktop icons guy, I'm betting you are not getting any help here. Better find the LXDE irc and mailing lists and ask there.

Comment: @satuon `pcmanfm --desktop` should start pcmanfm in mode in which it manages the desktop.